# How to use angular jwt to intercept token with ionic storage?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm getting jwt token from the storage to intercept to http requests in my ionic application. So for that I coded this program, but it gives error "Illegal constructor" because I can't just initialize ionic storage, but it has to initialize through dependency injection. How can I do this?

```
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular'    
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './auth/interceptors/jwt.interceptor';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'


function tokenGetter(): Promise<string>{
  const storage = new Storage();**//Error: illgeal constructor**
  return this.storage.get("ACCESS_TOKEN");
}  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: (() => tokenGetter()),
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['example.com/examplebadroute/']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    ErrorInterceptor, JwtInterceptor
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

This is how I save my token,

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  login(email: string, password: string){

    const data = {
      password: password,
      email: email,
    }

    return this.httpClient.post(LOGIN_URL, data).pipe(
      tap(async (res: IAuthResponse) => {
          const token = res.data.token;
          this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", token);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How you stores the token (share the code). In your token getter function there only initializing the storage. then it will be empty always.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create a factory function to achieve this

```
export function jwtOptionsFactory(storage) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return storage.get("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    },
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost'],
    blacklistedRoutes: ['example.com/examplebadroute/']
  }
}
```

In your module you have to change like this

```
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { Storage } from '...'
```

then

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  jwtOptionsProvider: {
    provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
    deps: [Storage]
  }
})
```

For ref see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt

and heading `Configuration for Ionic 2+`

Answer (score 1):

You need to intercept each api call and need to append token in header of that api call request, you need to use `http-intercepter` for that.

This may be helps you.

https://www.djamware.com/post/5c42ca7580aca754f7a9d1e8/ionic-4-and-angular-7-tutorial-http-interceptor-example

Comment: `@auth0/angular-jwt` library itself appends `Authorization` header for you. You don't need to add it in another interceptor